Using the number format in excel to represent numbers in Cr, L and K
Pure excel formatting question:
I want a number formatting to provide this output.

I have tried the following techniques.

[>=1000000]0,,"L";[>=1000]0,"K";0

This provides the following output

From what i Understood the mistake is happening here [>=1000000]0,,"L"; the double comma implies the number will be divided by 1,000,000 or 1 million, now is there any way to code the same by ensuring that 1,00,000 or 1 Lakh?
In an ideal world the code that should work would be:
[>=10000000]0,,,"Cr";[>=100000]0,,"L";[>=1000]0,"K";0 with the commas providing the following output

,,, = divide by 1,00,00,000
,,  = divide by 1,00,000
,   = divide by 1,000

Also when i try the same, excel throws the following error.


Custom Number Formats with conditions only supports two conditions, plus the null-case.  This is the reason that your final attempt fails (because it has three conditions)
However, there is a workaround: you can apply Custom Number Formats to Conditional Formatting!
This means you can create a Conditional Format for your range to "Format only cells with: [Cell Value] [greater than or equal to] 10000000", and set the Number Format for the Conditional Formatting to [>=10000000]0,,,"Cr";@ or even [>=1000000000]0,,,"A";[>=10000000]0,,,"Cr";@
